# JSF generate dynamic ids with hidden component

Tags: jsf

I'm adding hidden component in dynamic page for validation purpose.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{ifTrue eq 'true' ? true : false}">
        <br />
        <h:inputHidden id="staticComponentId" required="true" value="#{validation}"
                validatorMessage="Increase the value"> 
             <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" />
        </h:inputHidden>
        <h:message for="staticComponentId" errorClass="errors" />
    </ui:fragment>
```

Now, when this iteam added multiple times, it gives duplicate id found, as this validation binds with its own hidden component.

Is there is any way to generate view based Id to refer so that when multiple items included it will works fine.

Comment: HOW do you add it multiple times? That is a big part of the problem...

Comment: Application is designed as dynamic controls/templates so, it can be include at any page whenever needed, that is `<ui:include src="pages/yourPage.xhtml">`

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use it multiple times you should transform the fragment into a composite component. A 
composite component is a naming container which means that all components inside the composite 
component get the composite component's id as a prefix. So, there is no problem with using it 
multiple times.

Off topic:

```
rendered="#{ifTrue eq 'true' ? true : false}"
```

can be written as

```
rendered="#{ifTrue}"
```

Comment: I've seen that. I've suggested a solution which solves your id problem. If it doesn't fit your requirements you should tell why and concretize your question instead of voting my answer down.